# Define unicity criteria when declaring java.util.Set

Tags: java, set

Say that we have a class `MyClass` that does not override `equals/hashcode` but we want to use it in a `java.util.Set`. Is it possible to define an `equals` criteria at the `Set` declaration? The goal is to accept only one object from `MyClass` which respect the defined criteria. I know that we can check if the object does not exist before adding it but it's a bit tedious and we lose the interest of using a `Set`

Comment: You can't. But you could have a class `MyClassWrapper` that wraps your class and provides proper implementations for `equals` and `hashCode`. Then use that in your set.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't create a wrapper. Java designers did not yet finished the job ^^